# Crispy Form VariableDoesNotExist on Django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-crispy-forms

For crispy form on Django, I keep getting `VariableDoesNotExist at /`   `Failed lookup for key [form] in u'[{\'False\': False, \'None\': None,.....`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block loginForm %}
    <div class="container" style="padding-bottom: 70px;">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-6 col-md-offset-3'>
                <div class="well">
                    <legend>Sign in</legend>
                    <form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}" class="form-horizontal">
                        {% crispy form %}
                        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}"/>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock loginForm %}
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Div, Submit, HTML, Button, Row, Field, Hidden, Fieldset
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import AppendedText, PrependedText, FormActions
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm


class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('username', placeholder="username", css_class='input-xlarge'),
            Field('password', placeholder="Password", css_class='input-xlarge'),
            FormActions(
                Submit('login', 'Login', css_class="btn-primary"),
            )
        )
```

I don't understand, because according to documentation I am using FormHelper on attribute helper so I should be able to use {% crispy form %}

Comment: How does your view look like?

Comment: Sorry, which view? I don't have a view for this other than this class which is in forms.py

Comment: How do you render your template if you don't have a view ??? That's non-sense.

Comment: Not really. He's using the class as a view. `views.LoginForm.as_view()`. This renders the class as a view.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first argument to the `crispy` template tag is the name of the context variable where Crispy Forms expects the `Form` instance. So you need to somehow get a `Form` instance in your template context. If you were using this form in a view, you could do something like

```
def yourview(request):
    return TemplateResponse(request, "yourtemplate.html", {'form': LoginForm()})
```

If you want to have that form on many different pages, I'd suggest an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags):

```
@register.inclusion_tag('path/to/login_form.html')
def display_login_form():
    return {'form': LoginForm()}
```

And in your template:

```
{% load your_template_tags %}
{% display_login_form %}
```

(see also [the usual setup procedure for custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout))

Answer (score 2):

I came across the `VariableDoesNotExist` problem as well with `Failed lookup for key [form]`, but for me the problem was that I mistakenly used `generic.DetailView` as base class instead of `generic.UpdateView`.

Changing to `UpdateView` fixed the problem.

```
class MyUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):

    template_name = "object_update.html"
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyCreateForm
```