# Django: How to use views&forms of an app in main templates?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates

I'm using [edge](https://github.com/arocks/edge/tree/master/src) repo for quick starting a django project. The repo has an app called "accounts" which handles signin up, logging in, etc with crispy forms. However i'd like to allow users to sign up from the [home.html](https://github.com/arocks/edge/blob/master/src/templates/home.html) which isn't located in accounts/templates.

I have tried adding the following code to home.html:

```
  {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
  {% include "signup.html" %}
  {% include "auth_base.html" %}
  {% block form %}
    {% crispy form %}
    <div class="form-message">
      <p>
        Already signed up? <a href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">Log in</a>.
      </p>
    </div>
  {% endblock form %}
  {% endif %}
```

However since the main views.py can't locate views/forms in account app i'm faced with the following error:

```
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [form] in [{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {}, {}, {'view': <my_env.views.HomePage object at 0x7f0ed11cec88>}]
```

My project files are the same as [here](https://github.com/arocks/edge/tree/master/src) with only "project_name" being different.

I expected to be able to use the signup form in home.html. Can anyone point me the right way?

Comment: I guess this is because of the crispy form, check out this question and the answer to it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708802/crispy-form-variabledoesnotexist-on-django)

Comment: Yup, i thought the same @SammyJ however i still couldn't figure out which views.py/forms.py/templates i should add the inclusion tag since they are defined as classes.